java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for Ognl.createDefaultContext() in Struts 6.4.0
I'm encountering a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in my Java application using Struts 2 (v6.4.0) when trying to initialize the OgnlValueStack. The error message is as follows:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Map ognl.Ognl.createDefaultContext(java.lang.Object, ognl.MemberAccess, ognl.ClassResolver, ognl.TypeConverter)'
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setRoot(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.<init>(OgnlValueStack.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.createValueStack(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStackFactory.createValueStack(OgnlValueStackFactory.java:76)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.setContext(DefaultConfiguration.java:329)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:295)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.reload(ConfigurationManager.java:227)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.initialiseConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:84)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.wasConfigInitialised(ConfigurationManager.java:72)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:61)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:1124)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:625)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:48)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.listener.StrutsListener.contextInitialized(StrutsListener.java:43)
    ...

Issue Details:
I've traced the issue to the setRoot method in OgnlValueStack, which calls Ognl.createDefaultContext with the following parameters:
this.context = Ognl.createDefaultContext(this.root, securityMemberAccess, accessor, new OgnlTypeConverterWrapper(xworkConverter));

However, when I looked into the Ognl.java class in OGNL, the createDefaultContext function does not seem to have a matching method signature:
 public static Map createDefaultContext(Object root, ClassResolver classResolver,
                                           TypeConverter converter, MemberAccess memberAccess)
    {
        return addDefaultContext(root, classResolver, converter, memberAccess, new OgnlContext());
    }

Project Setup:

Struts 2 version: 6.4.0
OGNL version: 3.3.4
Tomcat version: 9.0.82
Java version: 11

Steps Taken:

Checked OGNL version compatibility: Ensured that the OGNL version matches the expected version in the Struts 2 dependencies.
Reviewed method signatures in OGNL: Confirmed that the createDefaultContext method signature does not align with the call in OgnlValueStack.
Verified Maven build: My application compiles successfully with Maven.
Ran the application on Tomcat: The error appears when I run my artifacts with Tomcat.

Questions:

Is there a mismatch between the versions of Struts 2 and OGNL that I'm using?
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Ognl.createDefaultContext?
Are there any known issues or solutions for this error with Struts 2 and OGNL?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Edit:
Upon further investigation, I have verified that the types in the createDefaultContext function used in Struts are correct. The method signature in Struts matches the expected parameters:

this.context = Ognl.createDefaultContext(this.root, securityMemberAccess, accessor, new OgnlTypeConverterWrapper(xworkConverter));
this.root: Expected type is Object.
accessor: Expected type is ClassResolver (and RootAccessor extends ClassResolver`).
new OgnlTypeConverterWrapper(xworkConverter): Expected type is TypeConverter.
securityMemberAccess: Expected type is MemberAccess.


The current version of Ognl has a method with signature missing in the code:

public static OgnlContext createDefaultContext(Object root, MemberAccess memberAccess, ClassResolver classResolver, TypeConverter converter) {
       return addDefaultContext(root, memberAccess, classResolver, converter, null);
   }


Only the problem the method returns OgnlContext instead of Map. It reminds me an incompatibility problem with new version of Ognl 3.4.2 is on the classpath.
The version of struts2-core 6.4.0 has dependency on ognl 3.3.4. You should use this version.

Well, I already have the correct version of OGNL in my pom.xml (3.3.4) but I am still encountering the same error. What I don't understand is whether the issue stems from OGNL or Struts, but it does not originate from my project. There is nothing I can change on my end because it comes from the Struts or OGNL repositories.                                           Here is my dependencies: https://gist.github.com/matgouleau/6f4f64c2c4fe20bda2822c234374dad3

Also if it helps my pom.xml: https://gist.github.com/matgouleau/9123b2b9d8d432682598065618e9d3fd

You have a property <ognl.version> but it is not get a correct version of Ognl. Ognl is a transitive dependency from struts2-core that is not coming because you have excluded it. Also dependencies you should download from the Maven central repository.

So, you're saying I should remove all exclusions and not import OGNL in my pom.xml at all, if I understood correctly? Like this? https://gist.github.com/matgouleau/2b12d355f050cebb540927091ec0d866. Even with this, I still have the error.

Tree dependencies updated : https://gist.github.com/matgouleau/598f36ecdeb8b04861e8151f8c8d4696

I have already told to you that you have used Ognl incompatible version regardless of what you modifying your pom.xml. And the problem is far deeper than you expected. If you have a wrong version of Ognl in the repository, then you should firstly update a repository with the actual version. If you can't download a proper jar from the Maven central repository then you have an option to build Ognl from sources. I have posted a link to Ognl project on GitHub.

Thank you for your help. You were right; the issue was indeed with the OGNL version in my local repository. I removed the OGNL version from my local repository and added version 3.3.4 from Maven by specifying it in my pom.xml. This resolved the problem. I thought running mvn clean install would be sufficient, but apparently, it wasn't.

@MamatSky If the problem is solved then mark it as accepted answer. Further if possible then vote this answer up to help others to choose the right answer.

@MamatSky I have edited your question to illuminate details and updated subject. Also I voted it up and removed close vote. Now you should upvote my answer. Also it would be nice if you do it for the linked answer too.
